Pseudo class :target doesn't work in Wordpress
The goal is to translate the title to the section of an id with margin-top property and highlight the <h2> element using :target CSS pseudo class when a specific link in the table of contents is clicked.
Here in the snippet below all works fine but if I use the same approach in my Wordpress website nothing happens when the link is clicked.


:target {
    margin-top: 50px; 
    padding-top: 20px;
    animation: highlight 1s ease;  
    transform: translateX(20px);  
    scroll-margin-top: 50px;
}


@keyframes highlight {
    from { background-color: yellow; }
    to { background-color: transparent; }
}
<div class="tbg">
        <h2>Table des Matières</h2>
        <ul id="table-of-contents">
            <li><a href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
        </ul>
 </div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>


<h2 id="introduction">Introduction</h2>




Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

I understand for the future, I edit my code to respect this line

In this case the example website URL is helpful though, because https://fastbest.belabori.be/amiante-debutants/ shows that the browser address bar content is not changing, when one of those links gets clicked. You must have some additional JavaScript there, that scrolls to the corresponding element position, but prevents the URL from changing to include the fragment. And if the URL does not contain the fragment, then no element will be in :target state either.

Also make sure the specificity of this rule overrides anything else in your site. Open devtools and view the styles on your h2, lower specificity declarations will have a strike through them
